# Mage registry key “application_params” already exists

Tags: paypal, registry

I'm using paypal express check out.In order review if i click place order button i'm getting this error. I don't have idea why this error coming.Any one can give some idea to resolve this issue.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:53:"Mage registry key "application_params" already exists";i:1;s:2487:"#0 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
        #1 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(338): Mage::register('application_par...', Array)
        #2 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
        #3 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php(98): Mage::run('', 'store')
        #4 /home/bd/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(96): include('/home/bd/...')
        #5 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Sales_Mode...')
        #6 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Mage_Sales_Mode...')
        #7 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1346): class_exists('Mage_Sales_Mode...')
        #8 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('sales/order_ite...', Array)
        #9 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Convert/Quote.php(128): Mage::getModel('sales/order_ite...')
        #10 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(170): Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote->itemToOrderItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
        #11 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
        #12 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(560): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
        #13 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->place('EC-5R2755885S34...')
        #14 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->placeOrderAction()
        #15 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('placeOrder')
        #16 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
        #17 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
        #18 /home/bd/public_html/staging/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
        #19 /home/bd/public_html/staging/index.php(97): Mage::run('', 'store')
        #20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:29:"/paypaluk/express/placeOrder/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the call stack:

```
Mage::register('application_par...', Array)
```

`Mage::register('application_params', ...)` is being called somewhere else in your code base, you need to find out where this is happening and determine why it's required.  Remove if possible or you can also use `Mage::unregister('application_params');` to unset the registry value before reaching the line of code in the call stack above (`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` line 338).  Hopefully it goes without saying that you must **not** edit `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` to resolve the issue.

Basically if you try to add a value to the registry using a key which already exists then an exception will be thrown which is what you are seeing.

Comment: issue solved.accidental call in item.php.thanks for your time

Comment: Ok great.  Can you mark the answer are accepted if it helped you resolve the issue?