# Automatically redirect to a store view based on the browser language ERROR

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to automatically redirect people to a store view based on their browser language.

Situation: 5 store views (en, de, it, fr, nl) Magento 1.9.1

I used this piece of code in index.php:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
/* Determine correct language store based on browser */
function getStoreForLanguage()
{
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    foreach (explode(",", strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) as $accept) {
        if (preg_match("!([a-z-]+)(;q=([0-9.]+))?!", trim($accept), $found)) {
            $langs[] = $found[1];
            $quality[] = (isset($found[3]) ? (float) $found[3] : 1.0);
        }
    }
    // Order the codes by quality
    array_multisort($quality, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $langs);
    // get list of stores and use the store code for the key
    $stores = Mage::app()->getStores(false, true);
    // iterate through languages found in the accept-language header
    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        $lang = substr($lang,0,2);
        if (isset($stores[$lang]) && $stores[$lang]->getIsActive()) return $stores[$lang];
    }
}
return Mage::app()->getStore();
}
/* Auto redirect to language store view if request is for root */
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') {
    header('Location: '.getStoreForLanguage()->getBaseUrl());
    exit;
}

#Varien_Profiler::enable();

#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::run();
```

It seems like the browser wants to redirect because if i type in: domain.com it goes for a second to domain.com/nl but after a second an error appears:

"There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

If i look at the error in the log file i see this:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:53:"Mage registry key "application_params" already exists";i:1;s:349:"#0 /var/www/webroot/ROOT/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/webroot/ROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(338): Mage::register('application_par...', Array)
#2 /var/www/webroot/ROOT/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /var/www/webroot/ROOT/index.php(129): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}";s:3:"url";s:4:"/nl/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0):

From this post: [Mage registry key “application_params” already exists](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36009/mage-registry-key-application-params-already-exists)

From the call stack:

```
Mage::register('application_par...', Array)
```

`Mage::register('application_params', ...)` is being called somewhere else in your code base, you need to find out where this is happening and determine why it's required. Remove if possible or you can also use Mage::unregister('application_params'); to unset the registry value before reaching the line of code in the call stack above (app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php line 338). Hopefully it goes without saying that you must not edit app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php to resolve the issue.

Basically if you try to add a value to the registry using a key which already exists then an exception will be thrown which is what you are seeing.